# Remove punctuation from a list of list of strings in python

Tags: python, punctuation

Lets say I have a

```
[["Hello, world!"],["Hello!!, WORLD!!"]]
```

I want it to produce

```
[["Hello","world"],["Hello","WORLD"]]
```

Comment: Have you attempted using a regular expression to match only the text you want to keep?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "punctuation." Your definition seems to include whitespace, something that I would not consider to be punctuation, and you additionally seem to require that the input strings be split into lists.  You need to more precisely define the transformation you want to happen.  (In the process of coming up with this definition, you may very well figure out exactly what you need to do.)

Comment: yes but I need it to produce like above

Comment: everything in string.punctuation

Comment: @NikolaIvanovic: So what have you tried?

Comment: You'll need to give us more information about what exactly you need to do, if you want a good answer.

Comment: @NikolaIvanovic "Like above" is not helpful.  You have only listed two inputs and two desired outputs.  That is not enough from which to extract an algorithm.

Comment: @Blender I tried it using documents1 = [' '.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation) for s in documents1] and documents1 being [["Hello, world!"],["Hello!!, WORLD!!"]]

Comment: After I remove the punctuation I would just use .split()

Comment: There have been a lot of punctuation-removal-in-Python questions asked over the last few days.  Is this some new fad, like a few years ago when all the kids suddenly decided that taking pictures of themselves face-down in strange locations was cool?

Answer (score 4):

I would use regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "Hello!!, WORLD!!"
>>> re.findall(r'\w+', text)
['Hello', 'WORLD']
```

Comment: Just a comprehension missing around it :) `(re.findall(r'\w+', text) for text in array)`

Comment: I need text to be [["Hello, world!"],["Hello!!, WORLD!!"]]

Comment: @NikolaIvanovic: I know, I'm not going to do all of it for you. Figure it out.

Comment: @NikolaIvanovic: The code that you had above should work: `''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation)`

Answer (score 0):

```
word_list = #your word list
punctuation_marks = re.compile(r'[.?!,":;]') 
new_word_list = []
for words in word_list:
    sub_list = []
    for word in words:
        w = punctuation_marks.sub("", word)
        sub_list.append(w)
    new_word_list.append(sub_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

a version without using regex:

```
import string

def remove_punctuation_and_split(word):
    return word.translate(None, string.punctuation).split()

remove_punctuation_and_split('Hello, world!!')
['Hello', 'world']
```